# Storing data in WinForms applications

Tags: c#, winforms

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm in the process of making a Windows Forms based application, which will involve a hefty amount of data storage. It will essentially be a sports simulator where there'll be hundreds of teams, with thousands of players.

So I need to figure out the best way to store this data. Windows Forms is relatively new to me as I've been mostly working with ASP.NET, but I've come up with the following ideas:

1. Compact SQL database in the program directory
2. Files containing the serializable objects.

Are there any other solutions out there that may be better? Or which of these should I pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are extremely vague, but in general stay away from serialization for any kind of persistent data store.

If your data is relational (it has internal structure, such as "teams must contain players" or "a player can be a member of only one team") then I suggest a relational DBMS such as SQL Server Compact Edition or SQLite.

If your data is not relational, I suggest a key/value store like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/).

Also, do not put data in the program directory; it may not be writable by the user. Store data in the user directory.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It will indeed be relational, and after some research I will go with SQL Server Compact, which has the added bonus of using LINQ-to-SQL with it

Answer (score 1):

If you have any need to execute queries against the data, I would stay away from serializing it in a proprietary format.

If there is only one user, then you could do something simple like an Access MDB via the JET drivers, SQLLite or NoSQL.

If there are going to be multiple concurrent users, you'll almost certainly need to look at a 'server' based SQL - e.g. SQL Express (although note the DB Size limitations), MySQL etc.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you to serialize data, and use LINQ against it when you deserialize it...

Comment: Yes, but how about other consumers of the data, e.g. running reports with SSRS, Crystal etc. And if any kind of performance is needed when querying the data, indexes will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Could use an .MDB Access database to store the data.  Not as reliable in my experience as SQLite.

Also, you don't mention if you need to persist these data after the form closes?  If you don't you may just want to use in memory DataSet's (or DataTables) to keep the data quickly accessable.